# How to obtain the bool from the controller (MVC) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to display a pop up based on the returned data from a `Controller-Action`. To do this I have created an action in the controller:

```
public async Task<bool> CheckSurfaceOnDB(#some inputs)
    {
        Surface surface = await ratesRepo.FindOneVolMatrix(#some inputs) as Surface;

        return surface != null;
    }
```

Then, in a .cshtml file I have a script where I have to access the bool output, how can this be done?

Also, I would like to know if there is a better way to proceed.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this that you want? (conditional with template syntax of razor)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-5.0#conditionals-if-else-if-else-and-switch

Comment: Did you mean that you have a razor page and that app will send http request to call your action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not mention if you are calling the `CheckSurfaceOnDB` from javascript. Based on the return type of the action it seems to be an ajax action. In that case change the action to be like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CheckSurfaceOnDB(#some inputs)
{
    Surface surface = await ratesRepo.FindOneVolMatrix(#some inputs) as Surface;
    bool found = (surface != null);

    JsonResult result = this.Json(new { status = found });
    return result;
}
```

Then in the javascript (cshtml - Razor view) where you get the result from the action:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Controller/CheckSurfaceOnDB',
    data: model,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    }).done(function (response) {
        if (response != null) {
            if (response.status == true) {
                //Logic for True
            }                             
            else {
                //Logic for False
            }
        } else {
            //Logic for False
        }
    }).fail(function () {
    //Logic for False
});
```

This way you can send multiple date from the action and then consume in the javascript. For example with True/False data you can also send a user friendly message from the action.

Note: If you surface object is a list then with the `Null` value you should also check if the list is empty or not. You can do that easily with LINQ. e.g.:

```
if(surface != null && surface.Any())
```

Comment: @vicvid431 hope this answer your question